# Real World Range of C-Band (3.7Ghz) versus EBS/BRS (2.5Ghz) mid-band 5G

Tags: microwave, cellphone, cellular, 5g

I am aware that with all things being equal, lower frequencies propagate better. Thus, T-Mobile’s 2.5Ghz spectrum should have better range than AT&T’s and Verizon’s 3.7Ghz spectrum. T-Mobile [advertises as such](https://img.lightreading.com/2021/03/768085/9348.png?_gl=1*1ckv9je*_gcl_au*ODg2MDgxMzYuMTY5NzA1Mjk4Mg..), but Verizon responded with [their own chart](https://img.lightreading.com/2021/03/768085/9398.jpg?_gl=1*1qzcfvx*_gcl_au*ODg2MDgxMzYuMTY5NzA1Mjk4Mg..) showing that 3.7Ghz actually has slightly better range because of power limitations affecting 2.5Ghz. [According to Verizon](https://www.lightreading.com/5g/verizon-s-c-band-vs-t-mobile-s-2-5ghz-which-is-better-for-5g-), “On the transmit side, EBS/BRS has power limitations that increase or get more punitive as an operator widens the beam width.”

Who is correct? What are the specific transmitting restrictions on 2.5Ghz and 3.7Ghz? Does T-Mobile even need to widen their beam width to the point of where power restrictions would take place?

Comment: The article says "Real world deployment is a function/combination of the raw physics, **FCC use rules and power restrictions**." Which implies FCC rules are what's imposing the power restrictions. Look into FCC regulations at those frequencies.